# NuGet Creds from Azure Service Connection in Docker container?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, nuget

In our Azure DevOps Build Pipelines we use a Service Connection for NuGet Restore like so:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'Our NuGet Service Connection'
```

Is it possible to use the credentials from the Service Connection in a Docker Build?

I read this documentation on [Managing NuGet Credentials in Docker Scenarios](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md) and there it is not mentioned. So I suppose it is not possible... But I thought I'll ask....

Answer (score 0):

By reference to this documentation: [Managing NuGet Credentials in Docker Scenarios](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md), you could [use the Azure Artifact Credential Provider](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md#using-the-azure-artifact-credential-provider) for this scenario since it provides a compatible experience between interactive developer machines and automated scenarios like Docker image builds. Thus it is possible to use the credentials from the Service Connection in a Docker Build.

BTW, you could review this blog: [Private Nuget package restore in Docker build & Azure DevOps](https://somakdas.medium.com/private-nuget-package-restore-in-docker-build-azure-devops-431fdfeae557) and [How to use the Nuget / Azure Artifact credential provider with a .net docker build container to connect to authenticated Azure DevOps feeds](http://blog.baslijten.com/how-to-use-the-nuget-azure-artifact-credential-provider-with-a-net-docker-build-container-to-connect-to-authenticated-azure-devops-feeds/) for detailed implementation.

Comment: Hey Edward, thanks for your answer! I only just found time for this topic again and I could not try the Azure Artifact Credential Provider so far. One question in advance: Does it work for all kinds of feeds or only for Azure Artifacts? We use JFrog Artifactory. I am not quite sure from the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Azure Artifact Credential Provider provides a mechanism to acquire credentials for restoring NuGet packages from Azure Artifacts feeds, so I am afraid that it does not work for JFrog Artifactory except Azure artifacts.